# How do I change the datasource of RDL report at runtime?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

I have 3-4 different environments like Development,Testing and Production
So there is different data in different database
and depending upon the environment,after deployment...respective datasource should get attached to the report.
Mean to say I need to change the datasource dynamically .

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: You need to add more details about how you access the report etc for us to answer.

Comment: In essence though, you may want to look at shared data sources: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155845.aspx